# Why doesn't my alert view controller work

Tags: swift, uialertview

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Title", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in self.alertFunc() }))
```

If I build this the alert view doesn't appear. What have I missed?

P.S. I know there are some similar question but to find out what they have and I have missed is hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to present it too on your current context:

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Add that row at the end of your `alert` declaration:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Title", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in 
    self.alertFunc() 
}))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to present the alerte view on your view.

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```